# Trouble Translating Magento

Tags: magento

I'm developing a shopping site using Magento, but I'm since the site needs to be for spanish-speaking people, I need to translate the site into spanish. I downloaded some .csv files to make the translation but they're not working. I've even tried to make changes on the english .csv files, changing the statements to spanish but it's still not working. Any ideas of how to  make this issue work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure, that your csv files are located in selected locale (i think /app/locale/es_ES) and this locale is selected in admin for your StoreView (System -> Configuration -> General -> Locale options)
2. Clear cache after changing csv files

Answer (score 0):

Just found it, you need to go to system > configuration > developer > translate inline, there yoou have to eneable the changes in the backend or in the front end and thats it. Its a really hard way to get it going, but it works. Any other suggestion is welcome.